# UITextView attributedText not setting

Tags: swift, uikit, uitextview, nsattributedstring, textkit

I've subclassed a `UITextView` to have a custom `NSLayoutManager`. I'm using it to display "Tags" in a textView. I had it working, but now for some reason whenever I set the `attributedText` property it doesn't set the text.

My function I'm setting the text in looks like this:

```swift
    private func updateText() {
        let attrText = NSMutableAttributedString(string: "")
        for tag in tags {
            attrText.append(NSAttributedString(string: tag.tag,
                                           attributes: [
                                            .font: UIFont.preferredFont(forTextStyle: .body),
                                            .foregroundColor: UIColor.white,
                                            .underlineStyle: NSUnderlineStyle.single.rawValue,
                                            .underlineColor: tag.color
                                           ]))
            attrText.append(NSAttributedString(string: " "))
        }
        
        attributedText = attrText
        print(attributedText)
    }
```

The `print()` statement at the end is just printing `nil`. But the `NSMutableAttributedString` isn't nil.

I also tried overriding the `attributedText` property of the `UITextView` to see if it was being changed. The code I used for that test is below, but it just printed out nil, and it wasn't being set anywhere except in my code.

```swift
override open var attributedText: NSAttributedString! {
    didSet {
        print(attributedText)
    }
}
```

`updateText()` is called when I set the `tags` array. I set the array, then call `updateText()` like this:

```swift
tagsView.tags = [TagsView.Tag(color: .systemRed, tag: "Flagged As Important")]
tagsView.updateText()
```

Comment: You are not setting anything to an instance of `UITextView ` anywhere.

Comment: Ah my bad, forgot to add that in the post. It's edited now

Comment: Actually, I see where the confusion is. The code provided is in a subclass of UITextView, so when I set `attributedText` it's setting it to the text view